# No release shutter w/o lens option Rebel t7

Tags: canon, camera-settings, shutter, photography-basics, shutter-release

I just got a 500-1000mm lens by Opteka and it came with a T-Mount but whenever I put it on it says “No Lens Attached” and I googled the problem and it said I had to enable “Release shutter w/o lens” but I have looked EVERYWHERE in my rebel t7. Even the custom options but I don’t see that option ANYWHERE. I am LOST. Where do I find this stupid option??? Also I should mention i’m new to cameras and photography:)
Another also, I like to do landscape / moon photography that is why I bought telephoto lens!

Comment: idk Canon, but on my Nikon, you can use non-electronic lenses by setting the camera to full manual. It then ignores whether or not it thinks a lens is attached. https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KLeD.jpg vs https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUsQh.jpg

Comment: My Canon doesn’t have that option and someone else told me that I would probably have to get a t-mount that can detect the lens when attached to the camera. Thank you for your advice though!

Comment: @Tetsujin, for Canon probably it depend of the class of the camera because I can make a photo with 5D Mark III and 700D w/o any problem (w/o a lens)

Comment: Do you have the T7 set to **Manual** exposure mode? You must have any Canon EOS camera set to **Manual** exposure mode to use the "Release shutter w/out lens" feature.

Answer (score 1):

All Canon EOS Rebel cameras (all Canon DSLRs) were designed to shoot without a lens attached. There is no need for a menu option to allow “shooting without a lens”.

If you have the camera in Video mode, you will get a message: “Insure a lens is attached”, but you will still be able to start taking a video without the lens. Many Canon DSLRs also allow taking photos while in Video Mode.

[image]

If your camera actually has a “no lens attached” message, and will not shoot, then that must be a new “feature” Canon has added to the firmware of the T7.

An AF Confirm Chip will trick the camera into seeing a lens that is not there, and will allow you to shoot. You can add one to the lens mount, or buy a new T mount adapter with one already installed.

[image]

The T7 is a very basic, beginner camera, missing a lot of features that other cameras normally have. You seem to have progressed far beyond the “beginner” stage, so it might be good time to upgrade your camera.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not see in [camera manual](https://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/0/0300029810/01/eos-rebelt7-1500d-im-en.pdf) the option to make photos without a lens.

Probably if you use T-Mount to EF-S adapter with chip you can inform the camera you have lens attached.

Comment: Hmm ok! Could you maybe link me a T-amount to EF-S adapter? Because i’m looking online but I’m not really sure which one to get and which one has a chip or not.

Comment: @AxG7, here is one example: https://www.amazon.com/Fotodiox-Adapter-Compatible-T-Mount-Camera/dp/B07KPKVJQ4?th=1  To be sure you have chip check for existence of pins on lens adapter.

Comment: Ohhh ok, Thank you! My moonshots will be amazing .